# Given three side of a triangle, how can I define whether it is a degenerate triangle or not?

Tags: c, syntax

We know that degenerate triangle is a triangle which has all three of its points in a line, and thus has all of its sides on top of each other. So there is a three sides of triangle and now I have to determine whether it degenerate triangle or generate triangle.

How can I proceed to solve this using C language ?

Comment: How do you get the points? Do you have int arrays with the point coordinates?

Comment: The sides are taken as int arrays

Comment: What do you mean the _side_ of the triangle? A line segment is usually defined by 2 points.

Comment: When you say "sides", do you mean side lengths? Please be more specific about what input you have, ideally with an example.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208577/find-if-three-points-in-3-dimensional-space-are-collinear/208605

Answer (score 35):

When you have three side lengths satisfying `a` ≤ `b` ≤ `c` and the sum `a` + `b` = `c`,  then the triangle is degenerate.

(Valid triangles have `a` + `b` > `c` and triangles with `a` + `b` < `c` are not possible.)

Comment: Yes - the nice simple answer.

Comment: Whats possible whats not is this even english i didnt understand anything

Comment: @nikoss: What's hard to understand? Or have you just stopped by to insult me?

Comment: Geometrically, the shortest path between two points is a straight line, no other path has this same length. So, if the two shorter sides of a triangle together are as long as the third side, then they must constitute a direct path.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: Are you explaining my own answer to me? This is my most upvoted answer to date. When I posted it as a quick answer to what seemed to me a trivial problem, I didn't expect it to get that many votes. But apparently people found it useful and it had stood in its original form for more than five years. Your comment now makes it look as if I didn't really know what I was talking about. Well, never mind. Thanks for editing my subpar English, I guess.

Comment: @MOehm. No your answer is great. I did edit the grammar for clarification. If you disagree with the edit, feel free to change. As far as my comment, I was just contributing the thought process I went through to realize your answer is correct which might be helpful to others.

Comment: Yeah, @JustinMeiners, your comment probably caught me in a bad moment. I had the (wrong) impression that you comment insinuated that there was an explanation missing in my answer. If there was a thought process involved when I posted my answer, it was probably more like: Oh, that's obvious. I'll keep your edit; I don't think edit tugs-of-war lead anywhere useful.

Answer (score 19):

If a, b, and c are the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, then

```
a + b > c

a + c > b

b + c > a
```

If any one of these inequalities is not true, then we get a degenerate triangle.

In simple term,first sort the a, b, c in ascending order then check below condition

```
a + b <= c
```

if this condition satisfy then triangle is degenerate triangle.

Comment: <= is the catch

Answer (score 6):

You need to figure out if points A, B and C are on the same line.  If AB and AC have the same slope then they are colinear (on the same line).

You've now reduced the problem to calculating slope which should be easy in C.

Answer (score 5):

Given the *side lengths* `a`,`b`,`c` of the triangle, you can calculate the triangle's area via [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). If the area is 0 (or smaller than a given threshold, b/c of roundoff errors), then the triangle is degenerate.

Given the triangle's *vertices* `A`,`B`,`C`, you can calculate the area of the parallelogram spanned by `(A-B)` and `(B-C)` by taking their [cross product's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) magnitude. If this area is zero, your triangle is degenerate. Also you can equivalently calculate the side lengths from the vertices and go back to using Heron's formula.